# clang++ - treat template class name as template in the class scope

Tags: c++, templates, clang++

It seems that clang++ (I tried clang 3.2) treats the name of a template class as a instantiated class, not a template for any occurence within the class scope. For example, the following codes

```
template <template <class> class T>
class A {};

template <typename T>
class B {
    A<B> member;
   // ^---- clang++ treats B as an instantiated class
         // but I want it to be a template here
         // this code could compile in g++
};

int main()
{
    B<int> b;
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to compile that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## C++03

Resolving `B` that way (called the *injected-class-name*, an implicitly-declared member of every class including template instantiations) is intended as a convenience. I've never seen it get in the way like that!

To work around, qualify the name by adding `::` before it (and if necessary, the name of the namespace).

```
template <typename T>
class B {
    A< ::B> member; // whitespace required to prevent digraph; see comments
};
```

## C++11

C++11 §14.6.1/1 specifies (emphasis mine)

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected- class-name can be used as a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a template-argument-list, **as a template-argument for a template template-parameter,** or as the final identifier in the elaborated-type- specifier of a friend class template declaration, **it refers to the class template itself.** Otherwise, it is equivalent to the template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in <>.

Therefore, if this problem occurs under C++11 it is a compiler bug. Workaround as above.

Note — for comparison, the corresponding paragraph in C++03 is

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (clause 9). The injected- class-name can be used with or without a template-argument-list. When it is used without a template- argument-list, it is equivalent to the injected-class-name followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in <>. When it is used with a template-argument-list, it refers to the specified class template specialization, which could be the current specialization or another specialization.

As you can see, there's already one special case allowing the identifier to be a class or template, depending on whether it occurs in a template-name. They just added a couple more cases.

Comment: @neuront: Woah... never knew about `<:`... +1 to ya both

Comment: @Cornstalks, It's a digraph if you're interested, for those who used to not have a [ key.

Comment: @neuront `<::` is now a special case of the lexer, but it's a new feature in C++11.

Comment: Your comment about C++11 allowing to write the characters without an intervening space is fun. See my answer for the explanation :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is nonconformant behavior as of C++11 because C++11 says that the injected class name (which is a name automatically declared within the class body) is a template when it is passed to a template template parameter. So your code should  only fail in a C++03 implementation.

However there is no need to open a bug report about this now. I have already done it way back.

Comment: *"However there is no need to open a bug report about this now. I have already done it way back"*, That's typical litb eh.. :-)